# sending a .rtf file with javaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, email-attachments, rtf

I am trying to get a file with the .rtf extension as an attachment with an email. I cannot seem to get it in my mailbox.

the code I currently use

```
try
{
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom( ); // this is filled in but hidden for this question
    msg.addRecipient();//  this is filled in but hidden for this question
    msg.setSubject("test email");
    msg.setText("body test content");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(receiveFile);

    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.attachFile(backupFile);
    messageBodyPart.setFileName("reportFile.rtf");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

receiveFile is the rtf file in question that needs to be send as an attachement.

Do not bother wtih server settings and such. I have send emails using this code so that works all just fine :). and had success sending .txt or .doc files as well so I know my info is correct. just when I try to send it as reportFile.rtf the mail just does not arrive. and I have tried 2 systems both together (the datahandler + source path and the attachFile path) and both did not really give me what I wanted.

Is a rtf file as attachment possible using javaMail or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: If the message is sent successfully but never arrives, the problem is in the server, not in the JavaMail program.  Perhaps the server is interpreting the message as a spam message?  Have you checked your spam folder for the message?  Note also that the msg.setContent replaces the text content of the message that you set with msg.setText.  You instead need to set the main text content of the message as the first body part of the multipart that you created, with the attachment as the second body part.

Comment: Yeah i have checked the spam folder and such :). Like i mentioned in my question i have send mails like this without attachements and also send mail with attachements as long as they were txt or doc or whatever. so I know my server information is all correct... the only difference between my succesfull attachment mails and fails is that the fails use a freshly generated one that is stored in the temp folder and ther succesfull one i just hardcorded a path to a file i had in like.. my documents folder. could it be that javaMail works weirdly with file that are not really stored on your pc?

Comment: The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) shows that the message is being sent successfully with no exceptions, right?  To use FileDataSource, the file **really** has to be stored on your PC (or some network accessible file system).  Stored in a temp folder is fine.  To prove that the message is being constructed correctly, before Transport.send use msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt")); and then examine the msg.txt file.  Or turn on JavaMail debug output.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it more closely with my co-worker we figured out that the email I used as sender was interperted as a spam and thus dumped it in the spam folder. now in itself this is not a problem since it was fine for testing. However it seems that if you keep spamming with that address the mail server indeed blocks like a good percentage of the mails i was sending. So this made it hard to debug since it sometimes got through and sometimes did not. the issues has been resolved now.